# Laravel Mail::queue breaks during unit testing, works manually

Tags: laravel, phpunit, swiftmailer

In Laravel 5.1, I'm queueing an email when an object gets modified with `Mail::queue`. For development, I have the mail driver set to `mail`, although intend to try a service later on.

During manual testing, `Mail::queue` and I receive the email I anticipated.

However, when my unit test on the object modification, PHPUnit gets stuck in a loop and crashes on a maximum stack limit exceed.

```
2.3541   25089024  62. Illuminate\Mail\Mailer->queue() C:\wamp\www\storytracker\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade.php:216
2.4081   28637896  63. Illuminate\Queue\SyncQueue->push() C:\wamp\www\storytracker\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Mail\Mailer.php:204
2.4091   28707008  64. Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\SyncJob->fire() C:\wamp\www\storytracker\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\SyncQueue.php:27
2.4091   28709640  65. Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\Job->resolveAndFire() C:\wamp\www\storytracker\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\SyncJob.php:44
2.4091   28711352  66. Illuminate\Mail\Mailer->handleQueuedMessage() C:\wamp\www\storytracker\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\Job.php:129
2.4091   28715800  67. Illuminate\Mail\Mailer->send() C:\wamp\www\storytracker\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Mail\Mailer.php:293
2.4091   28716240  68. Illuminate\Mail\Mailer->createMessage() C:\wamp\www\storytracker\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Mail\Mailer.php:173
2.4161   29276280  69. Swift_Message->__construct() C:\wamp\www\storytracker\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Mail\Mailer.php:446
2.4161   29277024  70. Swift_DependencyContainer->createDependenciesFor() C:\wamp\www\storytracker\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\Message.php:48
2.4161   29277152  71. Swift_DependencyContainer->_resolveArgs() C:\wamp\www\storytracker\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\DependencyContainer.php:129
2.4161   29277888  72. Swift_DependencyContainer->_lookupRecursive() C:\wamp\www\storytracker\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\DependencyContainer.php:348
2.4161   29277888  73. Swift_DependencyContainer->lookup() C:\wamp\www\storytracker\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\DependencyContainer.php:370
2.4161   29277888  74. Swift_DependencyContainer->_createNewInstance() C:\wamp\www\storytracker\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\DependencyContainer.php:112
2.4171   29370120  75. Swift_DependencyContainer->createDependenciesFor() C:\wamp\www\storytracker\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\DependencyContainer.php:312
2.4171   29370248  76. Swift_DependencyContainer->_resolveArgs() C:\wamp\www\storytracker\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\DependencyContainer.php:129
2.4171   29370744  77. Swift_DependencyContainer->_lookupRecursive() C:\wamp\www\storytracker\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\DependencyContainer.php:348
2.4171   29370744  78. Swift_DependencyContainer->lookup() C:\wamp\www\storytracker\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\DependencyContainer.php:370
2.4171   29370744  79. Swift_DependencyContainer->_createNewInstance() C:\wamp\www\storytracker\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\DependencyContainer.php:112
2.4181   29414856  80. Swift_DependencyContainer->createDependenciesFor() C:\wamp\www\storytracker\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\DependencyContainer.php:312
2.4181   29414984  81. Swift_DependencyContainer->_resolveArgs() C:\wamp\www\storytracker\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\DependencyContainer.php:129
2.4181   29415640  82. Swift_DependencyContainer->_lookupRecursive() C:\wamp\www\storytracker\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\DependencyContainer.php:348
2.4181   29415640  83. Swift_DependencyContainer->lookup() C:\wamp\www\storytracker\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\DependencyContainer.php:370
2.4181   29415640  84. Swift_DependencyContainer->_createNewInstance() C:\wamp\www\storytracker\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\DependencyContainer.php:112
2.4211   29521016  85. Swift_DependencyContainer->createDependenciesFor() C:\wamp\www\storytracker\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\DependencyContainer.php:312
2.4211   29521144  86. Swift_DependencyContainer->_resolveArgs() C:\wamp\www\storytracker\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\DependencyContainer.php:129
2.4211   29521560  87. Swift_DependencyContainer->_lookupRecursive() C:\wamp\www\storytracker\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\DependencyContainer.php:348
2.4211   29521560  88. Swift_DependencyContainer->lookup() C:\wamp\www\storytracker\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\DependencyContainer.php:370
2.4211   29521560  89. Swift_DependencyContainer->_createNewInstance() C:\wamp\www\storytracker\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\DependencyContainer.php:112
2.4221   29576160  90. Swift_DependencyContainer->createDependenciesFor() C:\wamp\www\storytracker\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\DependencyContainer.php:312
2.4221   29576288  91. Swift_DependencyContainer->_resolveArgs() C:\wamp\www\storytracker\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\DependencyContainer.php:129
2.4221   29576784  92. Swift_DependencyContainer->_lookupRecursive() C:\wamp\www\storytracker\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\DependencyContainer.php:348
2.4221   29576784  93. Swift_DependencyContainer->lookup() C:\wamp\www\storytracker\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\DependencyContainer.php:370
2.4221   29576784  94. Swift_DependencyContainer->_createSharedInstance() C:\wamp\www\storytracker\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\DependencyContainer.php:114
2.4221   29576784  95. Swift_DependencyContainer->_createNewInstance() C:\wamp\www\storytracker\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\DependencyContainer.php:323
2.4221   29577080  96. ReflectionClass->__construct() C:\wamp\www\storytracker\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\DependencyContainer.php:309
2.4221   29577640  97. spl_autoload_call() C:\wamp\www\storytracker\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\DependencyContainer.php:309
2.4221   29577720  98. Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass() C:\wamp\www\storytracker\vendor\swiftmailer\swiftmailer\lib\classes\Swift\DependencyContainer.php:0
2.4221   29577720  99. Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->findFile() C:\Users\thenickpick\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\composer\ClassLoader.php:300
```

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to increase the limit for XDebug's stack limit. It was set below XDebug's recommended value by default in my Laravel installation.